# Error at dataset creation

Tags: vb.net

I have an error with this function at runtime

```
Private Sub adultPay()
sql = "SELECT adultRate FROM roomType WHERE roomType = " & rumType.ToString & ""
connectDatabase()
Using da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
Using ds As New DataSet
Try
da.Fill(ds, "AdultRate") 'error here
Dim adultRate As String = ds.Tables("AdultRate").Rows(0).Item(0).ToString
Dim adultTotal As Integer = txtNoOfAdults.Text * Val(adultRate)
txtAdultTotal.Text = adultTotal.ToString
Catch ex As Exception
MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString, "error")
Clipboard.SetDataObject(ex)
End Try
DisconnectDB()
End Using
End Using
End Sub
```

the function is supposed to change the value of the adult total textbox when the number of adults has been put.
The error is as below

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: No value given for one or more required parameters.
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr)
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS dbParams, Object& executeResult)
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object& executeResult)
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, Object& executeResult)
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, String srcTable)
at Albergo.frmCheckIn.adultPay() in C:\Users\gman\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Albergo\Albergo\frmCheckIn.vb:line 111
```

The line 111 is the one in the sub wea u find
da.Fill(ds, "AdultRate")

Please help

Comment: Are you sure that a column named `roomType` exists in the table named `roomType`. It seems a bit weird (if not impossible) to have a column with the same name of the datatable.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the name of the table as WHERE condition

it's supposed to be:

```
"SELECT adultRate FROM roomType WHERE roomType_columnName = " & rumType.ToString & ""
```

Comment: i found the error, it was actually on the sql statement. it seemed that i had to string the rumtype

Answer (score 0):

i actually found out where the problem was. The roomtype needed to be put as a string e.g

```
sql = "SELECT adultRate FROM roomType WHERE roomType = '" & rumType.ToString & "'"
```

and not

```
sql = "SELECT adultRate FROM roomType WHERE roomType = " & rumType.ToString & ""
```

thanks guys for the help